# How can I use this Linq Query using it with a multiple parameter by Join tables

Tags: c#, .net, sql, linq

```
var list = dc.Orders.
            Join(dc.Order_Details,
            o => o.OrderID, od => od.OrderID, <-- what if i have 2 more parameters let say an ID and a REC on both table. ex.: o=> o.OrderID && o.ItemName, od => od.OrderID && od.Itemname then (o, od) but its result is error? is there another way?
            (o, od) => new
            {
                OrderID = o.OrderID,
                OrderDate = o.OrderDate,
                ShipName = o.ShipName,
                Quantity = od.Quantity,
                UnitPrice = od.UnitPrice,
                ProductID = od.ProductID
            }).Join(dc.Products,
                    a => a.ProductID, p => p.ProductID, <-- at this point too?
                    (a, p) => new
                    {
                        OrderID = a.OrderID,
                        OrderDate = a.OrderDate,
                        ShipName = a.ShipName,
                        Quantity = a.Quantity,
                        UnitPrice = a.UnitPrice,
                        ProductName = p.ProductName
                    });
```

is it possible to use this lambda expression linq query with multiple parameters by joining 3 tables?

--- UPDATE STILL ERROR -- :(

```
var header = DB.Delivery_HeaderRECs.Join(DB.Delivery_DetailsRECs, <-- Red Line on DB.Delivery_HeaderRECs.Join
                                q => new { q.drNO, q.RecNO },
                                qw => new { qw.DrNO, qw.RecNO },
                                (q, qw) => new
                                {
                                    DR = q.drNO,
                                    DATE = q.DocDate,
                                    RECNO = q.RecNO,
                                    CUSTID = q.CustomerID,
                                    CUSTADDR = q.CustomerADDR,
                                    RELEASE = q.ReleasedBy,
                                    RECEIVE = q.ReceivedBy,
                                    REMARKS = q.Remarks,

                                    ITEM = qw.ItemCode,
                                    DESC = qw.ItemDesc,
                                    QTY = qw.Qty,
                                    COST = qw.Unit,
                                    PLATENO = qw.PlateNo,
                                    TICKETNO = qw.TicketNo
                                }).Join(DB.Delivery_TruckScaleRECs,
                                w => new { w.DR, w.TICKETNO },
                                we => new { we.DrNo, we.TicketNO },
                                (w, we) => new 
                                {
                                    DR = w.DR,
                                    DATE = w.DATE,
                                    RECNO = w.RECNO,
                                    CUSTID = w.CUSTID,
                                    CUSTADDR = w.CUSTADDR,
                                    RELEASE = w.RELEASE,
                                    RECEIVE = w.RECEIVE,
                                    REMARKS = w.REMARKS,

                                    ITEM = w.ITEM,
                                    DESC = w.DESC,
                                    QTY = w.QTY,
                                    COST = w.COST,
                                    PLATENO = w.PLATENO,
                                    TICKETNO = w.TICKETNO,

                                    TRANSAC = we.TransactionType,
                                    FWEIGHT = we.FirstWeight,
                                    SWEIGHT = we.SecondWeight,
                                    NWEIGHT = we.NetWeight
                                }).FirstOrDefault();
```

I made up changes base on the answer but an error said above the statement:
"The type arguments for method cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly". i think it's talking about the parameters i've made..

Comment: What do you mean by `not on both table`? looks like those 2 parameters are some kind of *outside variables*?

Comment: sorry about that sir.. my mistake i have fixed it already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use anonymous type for the Join like this:

```
var list = dc.Orders.Join(dc.Order_Details,
                          o => new { o.OrderID, o.ItemName}, 
                          od => new { od.OrderID, od.ItemName},
                          ...);
```

The anonymous type will be compiled to use the autoimplemented `Equals` and `GetHashCode` so that the equality will be derived by the equality of all the corresponding properties. Just add more properties as you want in the the `new {....}`. Note that the order of properties provided in the 2 `new {...}` should be the same order of correspondence. The names should also be matched, you can explicitly specify the names to ensure this (this is needed in some cases) such as:

```
new {OrderID = o.OrderID, Name = o.ItemName}
```

However in your case the property names will be used as the same properties of the item.

**UPDATE**

This update is just a fix for your specific parameters, I said that the property names should be the same, if they are not **you have to explicitly** name them like this:

```
var list = dc.Orders.Join(dc.Order_Details,
                           q => new {DrNO =  q.drNO, q.RecNO}, 
                           qw => new {DrNO = qw.DrNO, qw.RecNO},
                           ...);
```

Comment: it has an error sir... i'll paste the whole code it says "the type arguments for method cannot be inferred from the usage
try specifying the type arguments explicitly"

Comment: @Oblivious7 could you post the whole code you tried? I'm sure there should not any error, BTW the `...` is what you have to fill yourself. your `o` and `od` of course should have `ItemName`, it's just an example.

Comment: i update already the codes sir.. you can check it above i put a label at it updated error..

Comment: @Oblivious7 please confirm this `q.drNO`, is that what you have or it's `q.DrNO`? Note that **case-sensitivity** is regarded. BTW, pleas re-read my answer, **the corresponding property names should be the same**

Comment: does it matter if on my Table 1 its drNO and in Table 2 its DrNO? must it suppose to be the same format?

Comment: @Oblivious7 you've not read my answer carefully, they should be the same names regarding of **case-sensitivity**, see my update for the fix.

Comment: oh sir i forgot about the parameters what if it has a parameters where do i put it and how? like i'm using a where condition on the header table like where header.DrNO == textbox

Comment: @Oblivious7 you can define some public parameter, use that parameter normally in your query but note that your query should not have any `ToList()` or `ToArray()`, `First()`, `FirstOrDefault()`... appended, we have to keep it **deferred**. Otherwise you have to pass your parameter into some method, in that method, you build your query, each time the parameter changes, you have to re-call the method to get the updated data (filtered by the updated parameter).